# How to add Location header to the http response?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, http-headers, servlet-filters

I have a Java project and I'm using Servlet in order to handle http requests.
I also using Spring

When I receive a request to create a new object (for example an account), I would like also to return the “location” header with the GET URL of the newly created object.
for example: location: /accounts/1000

I understand the header are added to the Servlet filter (correct me if Im wrong)

```
public class ApiLogFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("apilogger");

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);
       
        httpServletResponse.addHeader( "Location","the location value");
        
        try {
          
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
          
        } finally {
            String queryString = httpServletRequest.getQueryString() != null ? httpServletRequest.getQueryString() : "N/A";
            String logMessage = "URL: " + httpServletRequest.getRequestURL() + ", Query String: " + queryString + ", Response Status: " + httpServletResponse.getStatus() ;
            LOGGER.info(logMessage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

But I don't understand how to get the location value from the API

```
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
public class IgnoreRuleController {

    private AccountService accountService;

    public void setIgnoreRuleService(IgnoreRuleService ignoreRuleService) {
        this.accountService = ignoreRuleService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createAccount(@RequestBody Account account) {
        return new Gson().toJson(accountService.createAccount(account));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here
http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2013/07/post-with-location.html

you didn't need to do anything with the filter.
in the api itself:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> createIgnoreRule(@RequestBody IgnoreRule ignoreRule) {
        String response = new Gson().toJson(ignoreRuleService.createIgnoreRule(ignoreRule));

        final URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentServletMapping().path("/ignore_rules/{id}").build()
                .expand(ignoreRule.getId()).toUri();

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(location);


        final ResponseEntity<String> entity = new ResponseEntity<>(response, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return entity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you can pass the header directly throw your method signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create-account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createAccount(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeader, @RequestBody Account account) {
    var s = httpHeader.get("Location");

    System.out.println(s.get(0));
    return ...
}
```

In fact you can pass the whole request also which contains everything (Headers, Body, ...):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create-account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createAccount(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, @RequestBody Account account) {
    var s = httpRequest.getHeader("Location");

    System.out.println(s);

    return ....
}
```